# 'STAGE' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: mongoose, environment-variables, nestjs, mongoose-schema

## This is a backend server using Nestjs and Mongoose. But if I enter-

**> npm run start:dev**

it showing---
**'STAGE' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

something wrong with .env I think. Please answer if anyone can.

**CODES**

> **.env.stage.dev**

```
MONGO_DATABASE=dbName
MONGO_USERNAME=myName
MONGO_PASSWORD=myPass
MONGO_HOST=localhost:27017
MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://localhost:27017
```

> **app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { TitleModule } from './titles/title.module';
import { TopicsModule } from './topics/topics.module';
import { AssetsModule } from './assets/assets.module';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const username = configService.get('MONGO_USERNAME');
        const password = configService.get('MONGO_PASSWORD');
        const database = configService.get('MONGO_DATABASE');
        const host = configService.get('MONGO_HOST');
        const devConnectionString = configService.get(
          'MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING',
        );
        return {
          uri: `mongodb://${username}:${password}@${host}`,
          dbName: database,
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    TitleModule,
    TopicsModule,
    AssetsModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: [`.env.stage.${process.env.STAGE}`],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*> pakcage.json*

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "STAGE=dev nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "STAGE=dev nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "STAGE=production node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch --detectOpenHandles",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "offline": "npm run build && npx sls offline",
    "tsc:check": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
```

Comment: what's your OS and the shell you're using?

Comment: maybe you'll need to use a tool like [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Answer (score 0):

in package.json

```
SET STAGE=dev nest start --watch
```

or

```
cross-env STAGE=dev nest start --watch
```